# Alert With Color Change Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I want to send alert on tradingview with color change. This is an indicator named Trix. But dont have alert options. i try to add alert condition but dont work.

```
study(title="TRIX (Custom)", shorttitle="TRIX (Custom)")
length = input(6, minval=1)
out = 10000* change(ema(ema(ema(log(close), length), length), length))

upColour    = #33CC33
downColour  = #FF5555
hline(0, title="Zero")
plot(out, color = out[1] > out ? downColour : upColour)

*alertcondition(upColour, title="Buy", message="green buy")
alertcondition(downColour, title="Sell", message="red sell")*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

```
alertcondition(out[1] <= out , title="Buy",  message="green buy")
alertcondition(out[1] >  out , title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

added an option based on the comment

```
alertcondition(out[2] >  out[1] and out[1] <= out , title="Buy",  message="green buy")
alertcondition(out[2] <= out[1] and out[1] >  out , title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much. Just an other question, can we do this like ; give a buy signal if the color changes.

Comment: this way alarm triggered on every bar. i want to give alert only if color changes. Like this; if the color change red to green give buy signal. Other way sell signal. Thanks again.

Comment: Added a response.